# Why does my JS mobile nav work on all my pages but one?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I'm building a website, and I have a mobile dropdown menu that is controlled by JS (and appears with @media queries for devices under 400px).  My website is [jeffarries.com](http://jeffarries.com) (and the page I'm talking about is live there), the mobile nav works on all of my other pages, but not my *Politics* page.  The thing that isn't working is the bars that open and close the nav dropdown don't rotate and the `body` isn't set to `position: fixed;`.  Why does my JS work on all my page but *Politics*?

Thanks!

P.S. I can provide code, but it's like 250+ line and in different files, so I think it would be best if you view it on my website. (I'm not trying to sound lazy, so if you want the code, just ask and I will provide it)

Comment: We don't need to see all 250+ lines, just the ones that may affect the dropdown. Also, are you seeing any errors in your console? (hit F12)

Comment: @MikeC It was a separate JS script that was throwing an error and causing the rest of my JS not to work, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does my JS mobile nav work on all my pages but one?**

Because you have a javascript error!

Check your browsers console and you will see it:

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("javascript_warning").style')

If you look on line 331 of your politics.js file you will see the following function:

```
// Hides javascript warning message
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("javascript_warning").style.display = "none";
}
```

This is what is causing the error because document.getElementById("javascript_warning") is null and you are trying to call style on it.

Make sure that the element exists first e.g.

```
// Hides javascript warning message
function myFunction() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("javascript_warning");
    if (elem != null) {
        elem.style.display = "none"
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, I realized that it was an error.  Sorry!  Thanks for the error handling JS though!

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is:

Remove this line

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
```

Replace 'body' with 'document.body' in these lines:

```
body.style.position = "fixed";
body.style.position = "";
```

You should correct other errors appearing in console aswell.

Comment: Thanks for the code slimming and effort!   I'm accepting the other answer because it was first and more thorough.  Thanks Again!